# How to get json array in Flutter/Dart

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I would want to get the data for all "**name**" only from the array data.

I want to `print(data['data']['name']);`
 But it returns this error:
***Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'***

But when I `print(data['data']);`, it will return all data from "data":

```
"data": [
        {
            "created_at": "2020-03-16 16:10:51",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "id": 2,
            "is_active": 1,
            "name": "Maybank",
            "updated_at": "2020-03-16 16:18:06"
        },
        {
            "created_at": "2020-03-16 16:27:37",
            ......
    ],
```

**Call API Code**

```
displayBanks(BuildContext context) async {
    _callApi.refreshTokenApi(context);
    var _addressUrl = '$_hostUrl/banks'; //API URL
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _accessToken = prefs.getString('access_token');
    Response _response = await get(_addressUrl, headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $_accessToken'
    });
    var data;
    data = jsonDecode(_response.body);
    if (_response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(data['data']['name']);
      return data;
    }
    else {
      print(_response.statusCode);
    }
  }
```

**SAMPLE JSON DATA FROM API URL:**

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "created_at": "2020-03-16 16:10:51",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "id": 2,
            "is_active": 1,
            "name": "Maybank",
            "updated_at": "2020-03-16 16:18:06"
        },
        {
            "created_at": "2020-03-16 16:27:37",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "id": 3,
            "is_active": 1,
            "name": "India International Bank (Malaysia) Berhad",
            "updated_at": "2020-03-16 16:27:37"
        },
        {
            "created_at": "2020-03-16 16:27:37",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "id": 4,
            "is_active": 1,
            "name": "National Bank of Abu Dhabi Malaysia Berhad",
            "updated_at": "2020-03-16 16:27:37"
        }
    ],
    "links": {
        "first": "https://demo.local/api/banks?page=1",
        "last": "https://demo.local/api/banks?page=1",
        "next": null,
        "prev": null
    },
    "meta": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "from": 1,
        "last_page": 1,
        "path": "https://demo.local/api/banks",
        "per_page": 5,
        "to": 3,
        "total": 3
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

The exception message explains the issue clearly.

The property 'name' is inside an object which itself placed in an array. So you first decode the array. Then access each object using the index (0..n), then from each object, you can read the 'name' property.

Here you go

```
    class MyData {
    final List<Data> data;

    MyData({this.data});

    factory MyData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return MyData(
            data: json['data'] != null ? (json['data'] as List).map((i) => Data.fromJson(i)).toList() : null,
        );
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        if (this.data != null) {
            data['data'] = this.data.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
        }
        return data;
    }
}

class Data {
    final String created_at;
    final String deleted_at;
    final int id;
    final int is_active;
    final String name;
    final String updated_at;

    Data({this.created_at, this.deleted_at, this.id, this.is_active, this.name, this.updated_at});

    factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return Data(
            created_at: json['created_at'],
            deleted_at: json['deleted_at'],
            id: json['id'],
            is_active: json['is_active'],
            name: json['name'],
            updated_at: json['updated_at'],
        );
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        data['created_at'] = this.created_at;
        data['id'] = this.id;
        data['is_active'] = this.is_active;
        data['name'] = this.name;
        data['updated_at'] = this.updated_at;
        data['deleted_at'] = this.deleted_at;
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Darish thank you for your help, but if I want to print all property 'name', what should I do in my call api code there ? I'm sorry to bother because it's quite confusing as I'm fresh to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The error makes sense. The 'data' attribute in your JSON is array. So, you'll have to pass index of the item to access 'name' attribute - something like - data['data'][0]['name'] to get 'Maybank'.

Ideally, you should have a class which creates the instance from the JSON. In this case, the code snippet will look like :

```
Banks banks = new Banks.fromJson(data)
```

Now, you can use sites like [this](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) to create a class definition (including.fromJson).

Comment: Thanks for sharing Sukhi.